# Does overwriting a file actually overwrite it?

Tags: windows, file, file-io, filesystems, hard-drive

When I open an existing file and overwrite it's data (Lets assume I'm on Windows with an NTFS drive), Can I assume that the new data will be written over the original data's location on disk?

Comment: That is entirely up to the operating system and/or filesystem. C has no say in that.

Comment: Are you running your code in Linux or Windows or iOS?

Comment: What level of destruction are you looking for?  You won't be able to access the previous data by the file name after the `fopen()` call, but (especially with journalled file systems or solid-state disk drives) the chances are high that a forensic expert could find traces of the previous data on disk still.

Answer (score 7):

C has absolutely *nothing* to say on this matter.

Whether the underlying environment destroys the current data by overwriting it, writes in a new place and destroys the old data anyway, or keeps a copy of the original file somehow is entirely up to the environment itself.

In order to have *that* answered intelligently, you should probably ask another question detailing your operating system and C implementation.

Comment: Even the OS might have no say in the matter; when overwriting the same logical block on a disk or ssd, the controller firmware has the final say over whether it goes in the same physical location or not.

Comment: Even overwriting data might not completely destroy it, a file shredder will overwrite many times to remove ghost data.